# Android build error: ro.build.fingerprint cannot exceed 91 bytes

Tags: java, android, build, terminal, android-source

I'm building an android rom from the android source code but after about 5 minutes it gives this error.

```
error: ro.build.fingerprint cannot exceed 91 bytes: Android/mini_emulator_x86/mini-emulator-x86:5.0.555/AOSP/username02280306:userdebug/test-keys (97)
make: *** [out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86/system/build.prop] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file `out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86/system/build.prop'
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

How do I increase the **ro.build.fingerprint** size limit?

Plus I'm building on a Mac.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit `build/tools/post_process_props.py`. Change lines as follows:

```
PROP_NAME_MAX = 31
# PROP_VALUE_MAX = 91
PROP_VALUE_MAX = 128
```

Edit `bionic/libc/include/sys/system_properties.h`. Change lines as follows:

```
#define PROP_NAME_MAX   32
// #define PROP_VALUE_MAX  92
#define PROP_VALUE_MAX  128
```

Do

```
make clean
make
```

You can also run the second make command in parallel using syntax such as

```
make -j8
```

Comment: Hi and thank you. Can `PROP_NAME_MAX` etc, be set in boardconfig.mk ?

Comment: As mentioned @Matt, it leads to error in `frameworks/native/cmds/installd/installd.cpp`. To fix it you need also change value of `kPropertyValueMax` in `frameworks/native/cmds/installd/installd_deps.h`.

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, you can specify the build fingerprint string as command line argument to make using:

make -j5 BUILD_FINGERPRINT="....."

This will allow you to stay within the 91 byte limit.